# Unable to create user in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have the privilege of creating users,
but when I try to create a user, I get the following error from MariaDB:

> error changing account Access denied for test@% using password yes.

Please, what may be the reason for this error?

Answer (score 0):

This will help you: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-user/ 
Make sure you're logged in user has permission to create the user.

Comment: I already create user privilege but unable to create it .While creating it show the error access denied

Comment: You seemed to be logged in as `test`.  Does it have `WITH GRANT OPTION`?